# Android Location.distanceTo

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude, android-location

I wrote a function to determine the distance between two GPS locations.

```
public float latDistance(Location newLocal){
        // get distance
           Location tempLocal1 = new Location("ref1");
           Location tempLocal2 = new Location("ref2");
           // get lon difference
           tempLocal1.setLatitude(local.getLatitude());
           tempLocal1.setLongitude(0);
           tempLocal1.setAltitude(0);

           tempLocal2.setLatitude(newLocal.getLatitude());
           tempLocal2.setLongitude(0);
           tempLocal2.setAltitude(0);
           return  tempLocal2.distanceTo(tempLocal1);


       }
```

My question is, will this ever return a negative value?  my goal is to get a distance that reflects whether they moved north or south.. so if they move south from the starting location i want a negative value, and if north a positive?

It seems that i am always getting a positive number, but i can't tell if that is just my innaccurate gps readings

**EDIT:**

```
my code now looks like this.. and i know it irregular to ask people to comment on the logic, but its a difficult thing to test as it relies on a gps signal and to test i have to basically go out side and get a good signal, which pulls me away from my IDE and LogCat..

public float getLattitudeDistance(Location newLocal){
        // get distance
           Location tempLocal1 = new Location("ref1");
           Location tempLocal2 = new Location("ref2");
           // get lon difference
           tempLocal1.setLatitude(local.getLatitude());
           tempLocal1.setLongitude(0);
           tempLocal1.setAltitude(0);

           tempLocal2.setLatitude(newLocal.getLatitude());
           tempLocal2.setLongitude(0);
           tempLocal2.setAltitude(0);

           if(local.getLatitude()>newLocal.getLatitude()){
               return  -tempLocal2.distanceTo(tempLocal1);
           }else{
               return  tempLocal2.distanceTo(tempLocal1);
           }


       }

public float getLongitudeDistance(Location newLocal){
        // get distance
           Location tempLocal1 = new Location("ref1");
           Location tempLocal2 = new Location("ref2");
           // get lon difference
           tempLocal1.setLatitude(0);
           tempLocal1.setLongitude(local.getLongitude());
           tempLocal1.setAltitude(0);

           tempLocal2.setLatitude(0);
           tempLocal2.setLongitude(newLocal.getLongitude());
           tempLocal2.setAltitude(0);

           if(local.getLongitude()>newLocal.getLongitude()){
               return  -tempLocal2.distanceTo(tempLocal1);
           }else{
               return  tempLocal2.distanceTo(tempLocal1);
           }


       }
```

does that seem right?

Comment: latitude code will work , longitude is wrong, you shall not set to 0, set both latitue values to local.getLatitude()) reason: latitude influences the longitude distance, beacuse longituide distance shrink when moving north (raising latitude)

Comment: Testing: However you still can create an location object and create an Junit test for your code, which is highly recommended.

Comment: you lost me.. can you show me with code what you are saying?  whats wrong with setting the values of lat in getLongitudeDistance to zero but not the case with getLattitudeDistance?

Comment: also what if i wanted to measure altitude difference  would setting lats and longs all to zero be ok?

Comment: Altitudes are measured in Meters. You can Substrat that directly. DustanceTo does Not use the altitude. The distance is always a 2d distance.

Comment: Latitude distance are Not influenced by the current longitude. Because the distance between two neugbouring latitude degrees is always 111km. Look at the globe. The Latitude Rings are parallel. Not so for longitude. The distance between two longitudes is only at eqator 111km. It shrinks with raising Latitude, Look ar the globe the longitude Meridians are Not parallel

Comment: ok i get you now.. sorry to have you repeat yourself..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, distances are never negative!

For south movement you may extend your code :

```
float distance =  tempLocal2.distanceTo(tempLocal1);
// lat1: previous latitude
// lat2: current latitude
if (lat2 < lat1) {
  // movement = south
  distance = -distance:
} else {
  // movement = north or parallel aeqator or not moving
}
return distance
```

Although i reccomend to separate distance and South Movement (in future maybe you would like to detect an East-West movement, too)